# Zooming to feature selected from QListWidget using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have displayed in a QListWidget several features ranked according to their values from a field named "CODE". Based on this list I would like to select a feature and after a click on a QpushButton to zoom to the extent of this feature in the canvas.

Here is my crude attempt (I am still a beginner):

```
def append_features_to_QlistWidget (self): #associated to QpushButton_1

    #----------------function sample--------------------

    self.layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my_layer')[0]

    self.selection = []

    for self.feat in self.layer.getFeatures():
        self.attrs = self.feat.attributes()
        self.code= self.attrs[0]
        self.selection.append(self.code)
   
    self.dlg.listWidget.addItems(self.selection)
            
    
def zoom (self): #associated to QpushButton_2
    
    inds = [i.text() for i in self.dlg.listWidget.selectedItems()]
    
    attribute_value = {}
    
    for i in inds:
        attribute_value[i] = [f for f in self.layer.getFeatures() if f["code"] == i][0]
    
    self.layer.selectByIds(attribute_value)
           
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected(self.layer)
    

    ##Other incomplete attempt:
    # ids = [i.id() for i in self.selection] 
    # self.layer.selectByIds(ids)
    #iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected(self.layer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the code below should work (I simplified, cleaned up a bit and added small features) :

```py
class MyQgsWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, lyr_name: str, parent=None):
        super(MyQgsWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vertical_layout)
        self.list_widget = QListWidget(self)
        self.zoom_pushbutton = QPushButton("Zoom !", self)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.zoom_pushbutton)
        self.layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(lyr_name)[0]
        self.layer_feats = []
        self.zoom_pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.zoom)
        self.list_widget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.zoom)
        self.load_layer_feats()

    def load_layer_feats(self):
        self.layer_feats = [
            (feat.id(), str(feat.attribute("code"))) for feat in self.layer.getFeatures()
        ]
        self.list_widget.addItems([code for _, code in self.layer_feats])

    def zoom(self):
        sel_ids = [
            featid for featid, code in self.layer_feats if code == self.list_widget.currentItem().text()
        ]
        self.layer.removeSelection()
        self.layer.select(sel_ids)
        iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected(self.layer)


w = MyQgsWidget("my_layer")
w.show()
```

Comment: Awesome ! Merci beaucoup :) ! Could you just clarify why did you add `for _,` and `featid for featid` since we don't use it afterwards ?

Comment: `code for _, code`: we just want to have a list of codes, so we don't need feature ID (`_`). `featid for featid, code in self.layer_feats`: we want a list of features ID, so `featid` is mandatory here and `code` because we used it in the condition `if code == self.list_widget.currentItem().text()`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation ! But I was just wondering why we have to use featid instead of feat.id() ?

Comment: I just created a smaller subset of layer features data in `self.layer_feats` that is a list of features IDs and `"code"` field values. So, I think it's faster to iterate (but I don't speedtest it with `self.layer.getFeatures()`).

Comment: Aaaah got it now ! Thanks !